# Openshift ansible error for master( byo / origin / container )

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

I am trying to install openshift origin via ansible and get below error on master. Has anyone gotten into similar issue / Is this parsing error?

**systemctl -l  status origin-master.service**

```
● origin-master.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/origin-master.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Wed 2016-02-24 17:48:11 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 25168 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop origin-master (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25175 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker rm -f origin-master (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25181 (docker);         : 25182 (sleep)
   Memory: 1.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/origin-master.service
           ├─25181 /usr/bin/docker run --rm --privileged --net=host --name origin-master -v /var/lib/origin:/var/lib/origin -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc/origin:/etc/origin openshift/origin start master --config=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml --loglevel=2
           └─control
             └─25182 /usr/bin/sleep 10

Feb 24 17:48:11 ip-10-96-50-231.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting origin-master.service...
Feb 24 17:48:11 ip-10-96-50-231.ec2.internal docker[25175]: Error response from daemon: no such id: origin-master
Feb 24 17:48:11 ip-10-96-50-231.ec2.internal docker[25175]: Error: failed to remove containers: [origin-master]
Feb 24 17:48:11 ip-10-96-50-231.ec2.internal docker[25181]: F0224 22:48:11.517035       1 start_master.go:97] could not load config file "/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml" due to an error: error reading config: [pos 2313]: json: decNum: got first char '"'
```

> head -2 "/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml" apiLevels:
>   - v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has similar issues - I had defined the

```
osm_host_subnet_length=/8 
should be 
osm_host_subnet_length=8
```